# Get attribute name from proxy type without using reflections

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We use early-bound class for development. But occasionally we use attribute names.

There is a [way to do it](http://patrickverbeeten.com/Blog/2010/11/25/Get-attribute-names-from-proxy-types) using reflections, but reflections are not allowed in sandbox plugins.

What are the approaches to getting an attribute from proxy types without relying on reflections?

```
Opportunity.OpportunityId.AttributeName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- You can use a [`RetrieveEntityMetadata`](http://crmprof.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/how-to-retrieve-entity-metadata-using-net-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/) to the list of attributes that the entity contains.  You won't be able to use any early binding here, but you can inspect the results at run time to see what are valid attributes for the entity.
- You could also create a simple utility that uses reflection to auto-generate a class or enum that contains the list of attributes before you actually deploy.  Just add the class to your plugin dll and you'd have the benefits of early binding of entity attributes when developing your plugin, without having to do reflection at runtime.